# Two divs, in a row, with text in the center

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```css
html,body, {
    height:100%;
    background-color: white;
}
.main{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.col-md-6{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Home</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="core/css/main.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="core/node_modules//bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="core/node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css"/>
</head>

<body>

<section id="main" class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h1>Meubels</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h1>Meubels</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to make a page that lets you make a choice to either go to website a or website b. I have a design in my head, but can't figure out how to make two divs into a row, have them vertically cover the page and have text horizontally and vertically center inside both divs. I have tried all sort of things, but nothing seems to help.

I have included an image of how I see this screen in my head.

Can someone please help me?[image]

Comment: edited my question. forgot to include it :O

Comment: Do you need something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/g3xdr053/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use flexbox like so:

```css
/*Demo*/
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.col:first-child {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

/*Relevant CSS*/

.row {
  display: flex; /* Create flex context for children */
  height: 100vh;
}
.col {
  flex: 1; /* Distribute free space between columns*/
  display: flex; /* Make flex-container to align content */
  justify-content: center; /* Align horizontally*/
  align-items: center; /* Align vertically*/
}
```

```html
<section class="row">
  <div class="col">
    Website 1
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    Website 2
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: This was extremely helpfull! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

There are really a lot of ways to accomplish this depending on preference really. Check this link it has various ways for you to center stuff depending on how you have written your code https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Answer (score 0):

```css
html,body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
    }

    .website1 {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    position:relative;
    }

    .website2 {
    width: 50%; 
    height: 100%;
    background: green;
    display: inline-block;  
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    }

    .content {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        background-color: blue;
        position:absolute;
        left:0; right:0;
        top:0; bottom:0;
        margin:auto;
        max-width:50%;
        max-height:50%;
        overflow:auto;
    }

    .container {
    height: 100%;
    }

    .content p {
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 200px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div class='container'>
    <div class='website1'>
        <div class='content'>
            <p>Website 1</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='website2'>  
        <div class='content'>
            <p>Website 2</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Click on full page to see the thing you meant. The scroll is caused by setting the content (blue stuff) on 200px, which is smaller than the snippet box. Also, you updated your question right after i made this. So thats unfortunate.

Answer (score 0):

```css
html,body {
    height:100%;
    background-color: white;
}
#main{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.row {
  height: 100%;
}
.col-md-6{
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 49%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: grey;
  background-size: cover;
}
.col-md-6 h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Home</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="core/css/main.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="core/node_modules//bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="core/node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css"/>
</head>

<body>

<section id="main" class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h1>Meubels</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h1>Meubels</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

</body>
</html>
```

This one will work. You can also use flexbox to center h1